# Нужна ли запятая перед кто?

Tags: запятые, местоимения

Постепенно забываю кто я, растворяя свой разум среди пустоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Постепенно забываю (о чём?), кто я, растворяя свой разум среди пустоты.*

Кто я - придаточное изъяснительное (я - подлежащее, кто (есть кто) - сказуемое), выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.